# How to incorporate multiple orders of integration into my Integrator class?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, numerical-integration

I have a working `Integrator` class that will compute the definite Integral of basic functions of a single variable. I have tested the integrations of some basic functions and it appears to be working correctly.

I'm now at the point where I would like to expand this class to be able to perform multiple Integrals of the same function... and this is where I've hit a roadblock...

---

Here is my Integrator Class and some basic usage examples:

**Integrator.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

struct Limits {
    double lower;
    double upper;

    Limits() : lower{ 0 }, upper{ 0 } {}
    Limits(double a, double b) : lower{ a }, upper{ b } {
        if (a > b) std::swap(lower, upper);
    }

    void applyLimits(double a, double b) {
        lower = a;
        upper = b;
        if (a > b) std::swap(lower, upper);
    }
};

class Integrator {
private:
    Limits limits_;
    std::function<double(double)> integrand_;

    double dx_;
    double dy_;  
    double integral_; 
    int step_size_;

public:
    Integrator(Limits limits, int stepSize, std::function<double(double)> integrand, double dy = 0) 
        : limits_{ limits }, 
        step_size_{ stepSize }, 
        integrand_{ integrand }, 
        dx_{ 0 }, dy_{ 0 } 
    {}
    ~Integrator() = default;

    constexpr double dx() const { return this->dx_; }
    constexpr double dy() const { return this->dy_; }
    constexpr double integral() const { return this->integral_; }

    Limits limits() const { return limits_; }    
    std::function<double(double)>* integrand() { return &this->integrand_; }

    // This is always a 1st order of integration!
    constexpr double evaluate() {
        double distance = limits_.upper - limits_.lower;      // Distance is defined as X0 to XN. (upperLimit - lowerLimit) 
        dx_ = distance / step_size_;                          // Calculate the amount of iterations by dividing 
                                                              // the x-distance by the dx stepsize
        integral_ = 0;                                        // Initialize area to zero
        for (auto i = 0; i < step_size_; i++) {               // For each dx step or iteration calculate the area at Xi
            dy_ = integrand_(limits_.lower + i * dx_);
            double area = dy_ * dx_;                          // Where the width along x is defines as dxStepSize*i 
            integral_ += area;                                // and height(dy) is f(x) at Xi. Sum all of the results
        }

        return integral_;
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <cmath>

#include "Integrator.h"

constexpr double PI = 3.14159265358979;

constexpr double funcA(double x) {
    return x;
}

constexpr double funcB(double x) {
    return (x*x);
}

constexpr double funcC(double x) {
    return ((0.5*(x*x)) + (3*x) - (1/x));
}

double funcD(double x) {
    return sin(x);
}

int main() {
    try {    
        std::cout << "Integration of f(x) = x from a=3.0 to b=5.0\nwith an expected output of 8\n";
        Integrator integratorA(Limits(3.0, 5.0), 10000, &funcA);
        std::cout << integratorA.evaluate() << '\n';        

        std::cout << "\n\nIntegration of f(x) = x^2 from a=2.0 to b=20.0\nwith an expected output of 2664\n";
        Integrator integratorB(Limits(2.0, 20.0), 10000, &funcB);
        std::cout << integratorB.evaluate() << '\n';

        std::cout << "\n\nIntegration of f(x) = (1\\2)x^2 + 3x - (1\\x) from a=1.0 to b=10.0\nwith an expected output of 312.6974\n";
        Integrator integratorC(Limits(1.0, 10.0), 10000, &funcC);
        std::cout << integratorC.evaluate() << '\n';

        std::cout << "\n\nIntegration of f(x) = sin(x) from a=0.0 to b=" <<PI<< "\nwith an expected output of 2\n";
        Integrator integratorD(Limits(0.0, PI), 10000, &funcD);
        std::cout << integratorD.evaluate() << '\n';

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
Integration of f(x) = x from a=3.0 to b=5.0
with an expected output of 8
7.9998


Integration of f(x) = x^2 from a=2.0 to b=20.0
with an expected output of 2664
2663.64


Integration of f(x) = (1\2)x^2 + 3x - (1\x) from a=1.0 to b=10.0
with an expected output of 312.6974
312.663


Integration of f(x) = sin(x) from a=0.0 to b=3.14159
with an expected output of 2
2
```

---

I was thinking of adding another function to this class similar to its `evaluate()` function... It currently looks something like this:

```
double integrate(Limits limits, double dy) {
    double total = 0;
    dy_ = dy;

    for (int i = 0; i < step_size_; i++) {
        double yi = limits_.lower*i*dy_;
        double dx = static_cast<double>(yi - limits.lower) / stepSize;
        double innerArea = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < step_size_; j++) {
            Integrator inner(limits, step_size_, integrand_, dy_);
            innerArea += inner.evaluate();
        }
        double outerArea = innerArea * dy_;
        total += outerArea;
    }

    integral_ = total;
    return integral_;
}
```

And this is where I'm getting confused or stumped... I'm not sure how to implement this function properly when it comes to the limits of integration with respect to the inner and outer integrals.

Take for example the following integral below:

[image: double integration]

The inner integral's upper limit is based on y for each iteration of computation... This has to be done dynamically. The outer integral is straight forward as it goes from `[3,5]` as opposed to `[1,y]`.

I think I'm on the right track, but something in the above approach is totally off... I'm getting completely wrong values from expected or intended values...

Any and all suggestions and or tips are highly welcomed!

---

**Edit** - *Note - I supplied the wrong image above, that has been updated...*

The expected output should be: `65.582` with the correctly supplied function `f(x) = 1/2x^2 + 3x - (1/x)`. And when I try to compute the double integral I end up getting this...

And here is the added code to the driver program or `main.cpp`...

```
std::cout << "\n\nTesting Double Integration of f(x) = (1\\2)x^2 + 3x - (1\\x) from [3,5] and [1,y]\nwith an expected output of 65.582\n";
Integrator integratorE(Limits(3, 5), 1000, &funcC);
double dy = integratorE.limits().upper - integratorE.limits().lower;
integratorE.integrate(Limits(1, integratorE.integral()), dy);
std::cout << integratorE.integral() << '\n';
```

However, it is not printing anything to the console...

---

**Edit**

I wasn't getting output for I wasn't waiting long enough. The iterations were defined as `1000` by the step_size. This will end up generating `1000^1000` total iterations... I had overlooked this in the construction of the Integrator object. I had changed this in my code to have a step_size of `100`. And now my application is outputting a value of `2.68306e+189` which is clearly wrong! When I increase the `step_size` to `500` it is giving me something on the order of `6.62804e+190` which is still wrong.

Comment: Could you share some examples of input, output and expected output?

Comment: @cigien if you have the patience, it will take me a few minutes to implement that in my existing code and to give the expected outputs with the actual outputs... Keep in mind though, that I'm in Central Florida and we have been getting decent storms with power failures... so my response could be delayed.

Comment: Absolutely, we're in no particular rush. Take your time, and edit the question to include all useful information.

Comment: @cigien I've made some edits to the original post. I fixed the graphic image of the double integration test to use the correct function `f(x)`. I also added a snippet of how I was trying to calculate it within main.cpp... However, it doesn't want to display any result to the console...

Comment: @cigien I'm not sure if I'm getting the limits of integration or the ordering of the loops mixed up or not...

Comment: ... and here comes the storm, hoping there are no power outages...

Comment: @cigien I was following this Youtube video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvPBbNNMC-A&t=2377s

Comment: @cigien It took me some time, but since the weather has calmed down, I was able to work on it without having to worry about power failures. This was one of the reasons I started to post this question... part of it had to do with not stepping away and coming back later to re-evaluate what I've done, and the other part had to pertain to inclement weather. Now, I have it working and generating approximate expected values.

Answer (score 0):

After going back and watching the video again... I started to break down the double looping structure in my class's `integrate()` function.

I removed some unneeded parameters from both the constructor and this function's signature. I removed the dependency of passing in the `dy` since I'm able to calculate and store this value internally.

I had done a minor overhaul of my `integrate` member function. I'm now calculating both the `dy` and `dx` at the appropriate times using the appropriate limits of integration with respect to the `step_size`.

Instead of creating an instance of an `Integrator` within this function and using that instance's `evaluate()` function. I completely removed this behavior since I don't need to do this as this class stores an instance of the function of integration called `integrand` where this is an `std::function<T>` object. With this, I can just calculate the current `y` by passing in the `xi` into that integrand. Then I can use that to calculate the inner area for the summation.

My updated function looks like this:

```
double integrate(double lower = 0.0, double upper = 0.0) {
    // Since we are not using the inner upper limit directly
    // make sure that it is still greater than the lower limit
    if (upper <= lower) {
        upper = lower + 1;
    }
    Limits limits(lower, upper);

    double outerSum = 0;
    dy_ = static_cast<double>(limits_.upper - limits_.lower) / step_size_;

    for (int i = 0; i < step_size_; i++) {
        double yi = limits_.lower+i*dy_;
        double dx_ = static_cast<double>(yi - limits.lower) / step_size_;
        double innerSum = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < step_size_; j++) {
            double xi = limits.lower + dx_ * j;
            double fx = integrand_(xi);                
            double innerArea = fx*dx_;
            innerSum += innerArea;
        }
        double outerArea = innerSum * dy_;
        outerSum += outerArea;
    }

    integral_ = outerSum;
    return integral_;
}
```

And here is the usage of this function within my main class:

```
std::cout << "\n\nTesting Double Integration of f(x) = (1\\2)x^2 + 3x - (1\\x) from [3,5] and [1,y]\nwith an expected output of 65.582\n";
Integrator integratorE(Limits(3, 5), 100, &funcC);
//double dy = integratorE.limits().upper - integratorE.limits().lower;
integratorE.integrate(1);
std::cout << integratorE.integral() << '\n';
```

And this is giving me an output of:

```
Testing Double Integration of f(x) = (1\2)x^2 + 3x - (1\x) from [3,5] and [1,y]
with an expected output of 65.582
64.6426
```

With a `step_size` of `100` iterations and an output of:

```
Testing Double Integration of f(x) = (1\2)x^2 + 3x - (1\x) from [3,5] and [1,y]
with an expected output of 65.582
65.3933
```

With a `step_size` of `500` iterations.

So as this class now stands, I can use `evaluate()` to perform a single definite integration of a single variable and I can use `integrate(lower,upper)` to perform at least a double definite integration of a single variable.